# SSD migration titsup

Tags: boot, ssd, grub

I'm migrating win7 to an SSD following [this](http://lifehacker.com/5837543/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows) guide. I've happily cloned my c: to a freshly created m: partition on the SSD, and, perhaps prematurely, formatted my c:.

Now the problems start. The SSD previously had ubuntu on it, and now when I boot, I see a `grub emergency mode >` prompt. I've run my Win7 emergency repair disk startup repair a number of times, but it's not getting rid of grub. How do I sort out my MBR to get windows starting?

Comment: The repair you need is `fixmbr`.

Comment: World of pain. I got past this problem, past the next one, but never managed to create a system partition on the ssd. Clean install of windows fixed it.